findSpanStyle not implemented in this parser reportLab
When i run the below code in py3 environment with reportlab version 4.0.0
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

sample_txt = '<p><span style=\'font-family: Arial; background-color: #ffffff;\'>Sample Content</span></p>'
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
para_text = Paragraph(sample_txt, styles['Normal'])

Getting below error,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kvenugopal/venudocs/pypdfissue/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 3215, in parse
    self.feed(text)
  File "/home/kvenugopal/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/html/parser.py", line 110, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/home/kvenugopal/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/html/parser.py", line 170, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "/home/kvenugopal/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/html/parser.py", line 344, in parse_starttag
    self.handle_starttag(tag, attrs)
  File "/home/kvenugopal/venudocs/pypdfissue/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 3238, in handle_starttag
    start(attrs or {})
  File "/home/kvenugopal/venudocs/pypdfissue/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 2832, in start_span
    style = self.findSpanStyle(A.pop('style'))
  File "/home/kvenugopal/venudocs/pypdfissue/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py", line 3205, in findSpanStyle
    raise ValueError('findSpanStyle not implemented in this parser')
ValueError: findSpanStyle not implemented in this parser

Any solutions for this. I am not seeing anything in the document as well. This was working with reportlab version 2.x.
